# How to display taxonomies values in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I registered a taxonomy:

```
<?php function event_cities_init() {
register_taxonomy( 'event-cities', array( 'events' ), array(
    'hierarchical'      => false,
    'public'            => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus' => false,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => false,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => array('slug' => 'city'),
    'capabilities'      => array(
        'manage_terms'  => 'edit_posts',
        'edit_terms'    => 'edit_posts',
        'delete_terms'  => 'edit_posts',
        'assign_terms'  => 'edit_posts'
    ),
    'labels'            => array(
        'name'                       => __( 'City', 'projecttitle' ),
        'singular_name'              => _x( 'City', 'taxonomy general name', 'projecttitle' ),
        'search_items'               => __( 'Search Cities', 'projecttitle' ),
        'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Cities', 'projecttitle' ),
        'all_items'                  => __( 'All Cities', 'projecttitle' ),
        'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent City', 'projecttitle' ),
        'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent City:', 'projecttitle' ),
        'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit City', 'projecttitle' ),
        'update_item'                => __( 'Update City', 'projecttitle' ),
        'add_new_item'               => __( 'New City', 'projecttitle' ),
        'new_item_name'              => __( 'New City', 'projecttitle' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate Cities with commas', 'projecttitle' ),
        'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove Cities', 'projecttitle' ),
        'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used Cities', 'projecttitle' ),
        'not_found'                  => __( 'No Cities found.', 'projecttitle' ),
        'menu_name'                  => __( 'City', 'projecttitle' ),
    ),
    'show_in_rest'      => true,
    'rest_base'         => 'event-cities',
    'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller',
) );}add_action( 'init', 'event_cities_init' );
```

How can I simply display the "name" of a certain taxonomy?
I tried the following code and it prints out a large array, but I only want to have the name of it and I can't catch it.

```
  $terms = get_terms('event-types'); 
  var_dump($terms);
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can get taxonomy name with this code : `get_taxonomy('event-types')->labels->name`

Comment: Well, maybe I was not precise enough. I read (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_taxonomy) that it does NOT return the list of terms associated with the taxonomy. But that's what I want to have. So how I have to use the get_term() function correctly?

Comment: Is 

`get_term_by('id'*, 'name', 'event-cities');`

the correct way?

* where can I find the id?!

Comment: You can find term id in admin panel term edit screen URL as tag_ID like tag_ID=17575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_terms() function returns all terms of specified taxonomy. You can use foreach loop like below to iterate through your terms and use name property of term object to access term name :

```
$terms = get_terms('event-types'); 
foreach($terms as $term) {
    echo $term->name;
}
```

You can get specific term as below

```
get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy)
```

e.g.

```
get_term_by( 'id', '19', 'event-types')
```